# Start menu and taskbar are freezing

Tags: windows, windows-10

This problem started happening recently, for no apparent reason. The start menu doesn't pop up when clicking on the start menu icon or using the start menu key, calendar doesn't open, and it's impossible to use taskbar to switch to some applications (nothing happens when clicking on their icons in the taskbar). It lasts for a few minutes and then stops again. No viruses found. I tried repairing Windows and even reinstalling it from scratch, but that didn't help.
Also, I noticed that the problem goes away for a while when I kill the explorer process from TaskMan and restart it, but after some time it happens again.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you done any updates to Windows or drivers (especially display) when this happened?

Comment: @harrymc well... with Windows 10 it's more about updates that *it* does, not that you do.

Comment: With the ammount of information you provide it is impossible to provide a qualified answer. Please provide relevant output of the event viewer

Comment: @mashuptwice I can't send you my PC. If you need more information, just ask. wrt the event viewer, there is nothing unusual there.

Comment: @user626528 good luck getting an answer with that attitude.

Comment: You could at least consult the Windows Update history to know if anything was installed at that date. The date of the display driver would also be useful.

Comment: Since the problem still occurs after a clean install, the issue isn't the OS and is either a problem with a 3rd party driver, 3rd party application, user-modified Registry keys, and possibly a context menu item, but the latter would generally not affect the Taskbar unless a context menu for the Taskbar was customized. What does ending the DWM system process in Task Manager result with?

Comment: Are there any useful messages in the Event Viewer?

Comment: Give it a try with a USB pen loaded with linux. Start the different OS so you can try to exclude an harware origin of the problem. Give it a look to the log files under linux (`dmesg`,...) you may get some info. Then with program as [memtest86](https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm) do some extensive hardware tests of the memory... Once I found a computer with rare memory failures that freezed the OS in a similar way. Of course give it a check (if SMART is enabled) to the drive health.

Comment: @JW0914 restarting DWM doesn't change anything. Only restarting explorer does.

Answer (score 0):

Corrupted user account files may be responsible for freezing Windows 10 taskbar and start menu. Therefore, another solution you can try is to create a new administrator account and log in to the new administrator account. If the start menu and taskbar works, transfer your files to the new account, and the delete the old one.

Comment: It's not a corrupted user profile if it occurs after a clean install, unless restoring the old install's user Registry hives.